# Getting PIDs of siblings

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, pid, siblings

I'm starting several parallel bash scripts (siblings) from within another bash script (parent). How do I best get within these scripts the PIDs of the other siblings?

The parent process I can get with

```
ps -p $$ -o ppid --no-heading
```

but I could not figure out how to get it's child processes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `ps --ppid <parent-process-id>` (or) `pgrep -P <parent-process-id>`

From the `man` page of [`ps`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ps&manpath=SuSE+Linux/i386+11.3)

> --ppid pidlist    Select by parent process ID. This selects the processes with a
>           parent process ID in pidlist. That is, it selects processes
>           that are children of those listed in pidlist.

For [`pgrep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep)

> -P ppid,...
>   Only match processes whose parent process ID is listed.

Comment: for completeness, ``pgrep -P `ps -p $$ -o ppid --no-heading`` or ``ps --ppid `ps -p $$ -o ppid --no-heading` -o "pid" --noheading`` to get the siblings

Comment: or better `pgrep -P $(ps -p $$ -o ppid --no-heading)` or `ps --ppid $(ps -p $$ -o ppid --no-heading) -o "pid" --noheading` to get the siblings